# R: Sumif equivalent from one dataframe to another

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sum

I have two dataframes that look somewhat like this (they're much bigger)

```
df1 <- data.frame(center = c("5012","5012","5025"), 
                  product = c("Apple","Grape","Apple"),
                  value = c(20,30,50))

df1:
            Center   Product     Value
    1       5012       Apple      20
    2       5012       Grape      30
    3       5025       Apple      50

df2 <- data.frame(center = c("5012","5012","5012","5012","5012","5025"),
                  profitCenter = c("A","B","C","D","A","A"),
                  product = c("Apple","Apple","Apple", "Apple","Grape","Apple"),
                  volume = c(20,30,50,70,60,80))

df2:
        Center  Profitcenter  Product   Volume
1       5012        A          Apple     20
2       5012        B          Apple     30
3       5012        C          Apple     50
4       5012        D          Apple     70
5       5012        A          Grape     60
6       5025        A          Apple     80
```

I wanted to get the sum of the "volume" column from DF2 by "center" and "product" into DF1. In excel I would do a sumif, but I'm struggling to think on how to properly do this with R:

```
DF1:
            Center   Product     Value  Volume
    1       5012       Apple      20      170
    2       5012       Grape      30      60
    3       5025       Apple      50      80
```

Currently I'm creating an aggregated version of DF2 (with dplyr's group_by) and then doing a left_join, but I have to do this a few more times and I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: With `dplyr` this is a straight forward merge and summarize: `df1 %>% left_join(df2) %>% group_by(center, product, value) %>% summarize(Volume=sum(volume))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @MrFlick commented but I would prefer to *first* `summarise` in/works with `df2` and *then* add the resulting column to `df1`. But outcome and performance are the same. As @r2evans pointed out:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% 
  group_by(center, product) %>% 
  summarise(Volume=sum(volume)) %>% 
  right_join(df1,by=c("center","product"))
```

Or:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(
    df2 %>% 
      group_by(center,product) %>% 
      summarise(sum(volume)),
  by=c("center","product")
  )
```

Or (for avoiding nesting, thanks @r2evans again):

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% 
  group_by(center, product) %>% 
  summarise(Volume=sum(volume)) %>% 
  left_join(df1,.,by=c("center","product"))
```

Output:

```
  center product value sum(volume)
1   5012   Apple    20         170
2   5012   Grape    30          60
3   5025   Apple    50          80
```

Comment: Subjectively, nested `%>%` appears more complicated. How about `df2 %>% group_by(center, product) %>% summarise(Volume=sum(volume)) %>% right_join(df1,by=c("center","product"))`?

Comment: That's totally right. I'm used to `left_join` and nesting. @r2evans

Comment: (Not at _all_ arguing, each has their own style/preferences. I see this style a lot, so I'm not picking on you.) One of the selling points for `magrittr::%>%` is *'avoiding nested function calls"* (from https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/), does it seem odd to you that its use is now comfortably in the realm it is attempting to reduce? Granted, nesting one level as here is a lot different from reading `calls(nested(multiple(x)))`. Again, not critical, just curious and conversational. I'll stop now :-)

Comment: BTW, if your rationale for nesting is heavily due to your preference for `left_join`, then one could always do `df2 %>% group_by(center, product) %>% summarise(Volume=sum(volume)) %>% left_join(df1,.,by=c("center","product"))` for the same effect, no nesting. Granted, that won't work with the base `|>` pipe, but that's not in the question or your answer ...

Comment: Oh thanks for your help @r2evans I didn't know `left_join(df1,.,...)`. I'll start using those alternatives. And I'll update the answer. I appreciate all this suggestions, they are really useful for improving and helping me to avoid some bad habits ;)